# LinearLayout поверх другого элемента

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Есть LinearLayout А, и button, нужно сделат так, чтобы они были внутри другого LinearLayout B и при этом button находился под LinearLayout A. Как это можно реализовать? То есть что бы LinearLayout перекрывал button

Comment: constraint лучше использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<LinearLayout B>

  <FrameLayout>

     <Button/>

     <LinearLayout A/>

  </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout B>
```